# Div using remaining width

Tags: css, smartadmin

I’m using SmartAdmin.  I have a widget that is using the Left Tabs.  On the right side I’m attempting to have a DataTables table take up 100% of the remaining width.  Currently the table takes up 100% width of the parent div and is below the left tabs.

SmartAdmin: http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/#ajax/dashboard.html

How it looks:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKpIW.jpg

How I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWqOe.jpg

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xq9mpom6/

```
Must
Enter
Code
For JSFiddle Link
```

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net instead of pastebin, so you can recreate the problem easier, and we can also help you easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display:table for parent, and display:table-cell for children, like so:

```
.widget-body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.widget-body .tabs-left {
    display: table-cell;
}

.widget-body .dataTables_wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Updated JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xq9mpom6/2/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty cut and dry case of needing multiple columns in an area. For pure CSS solutions you have a ton of options.

Given the following markup:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='tabs-left'>
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class='data-table'>
        [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

Percentage widths with floats:

```
.tabs-left {
   width: 10%;
   min-width: 200px;
   float: left;
}
.data-table {
   width: 90%;
   min-width: 720px; // Arbitrary width. Should min-width of parent minus min-width of the left tabs
   float: left;
}
```

Fixed and percentage width with floats:

```
.tabs-left {
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
}
.data-table {
   width: calc(100% - 200px);
   min-width: 720px;
   float: left;
}
```

Flexbox (will need vendor prefixing):

```
.wrapper { 
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row;
}
.tabs-left {
   width: 200px;
}
.data-table {
   flex-grow 1
}
```

Display table:

```
.wrapper { 
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.tabs-left {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 200px;
}
.data-table {
   display: table-cell;
}
```